# Erro ao gerar obj com JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho o código s seguir que funciona bem

```js
  var ctx = $( "#myChart" );
  var datasets = 
  [ {
   label: "Gcéu 1",
   data: [ {
    x: "2019/03/01",
    y: 20
   }, {
    x: "2019/03/02",
    y: 10
   }, {
    x: "2019/03/05",
    y: 5
   } ]
   } , 
   {
   label: "Gcéu 2",
   data: [ {
    x: "2019/03/01",
    y: 15
   }, {
    x: "2019/03/03",
    y: 10
   }, {
    x: "2019/03/10",
    y: 2
   } ]
   } , 
   {
   label: "Gcéu 3",
   data: [ {
    x: "2019/03/07",
    y: 7
   }, {
    x: "2019/03/08",
    y: 8
   }, {
    x: "2019/03/19",
    y: 9
   } ]
  } ];
  
  var scatterChart = new Chart( ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
    datasets: datasets
   },
   options: {
    title: {
     display: true,
     text: 'Gráfico presenças dos Gcéus'
    },
    scales: {
     yAxes: [ 
     {
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Presenças'
      }
     }],
     xAxes: [ 
     {
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Datas'
      },
      type: 'time',
      time: {
       unit: 'day',
       displayFormats: {
        'day': 'DD/MM/YYYY',
       }
      },
      ticks: {
       source: 'data'
      }
     } ]
    }
   }
  } );
```

```html
 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Mas a variavel datasets acima é estátiva e pretendo puxar do banco para gerar o gráfico como abaixo mas está dando erro:

```js
//dataRelatorio vem do PHP e a saida é como a imagem abaixo um json
  var dataRelatorio = window.dadosRel;
 
 var ctx = $(".line-chart");

 var dados = "[";
 
 for (rel in dataRelatorio) {

  dados += "{ 'label': 'Gcéu " + rel + "', 'data': [";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(dataRelatorio).length; i++) { 

   dados += "{ 'x': '" + dataRelatorio[rel][i]['data'] + "', 'y': " + dataRelatorio[rel][i]['decisoes'] + "},";  

  }
  dados = dados.substring(0, dados.length - 1);
  dados += "]},"; 

 };

    dados += "]";
 dados = dados.substring(0, dados.length - 1);
    console.log(dados);
 dados = JSON.parse(dados);
    console.log(dados);
 
 var scatterChart = new Chart( ctx, {
  
  type: 'line',
  data: {
   datasets: [dados]
  },
  options: {
   title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Gráfico crescimento dos Gcéus'
   },
   scales: {
    yAxes: [ 
    {
     scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
       labelString: 'Descisões no período)'
     }
    }],
    xAxes: [ 
    {
     scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
       labelString: 'Datas'
     },
     type: 'time',
     time: {
      unit: 'day',
      displayFormats: {
       'day': 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      }
     },
     ticks: {
      source: 'data'
     }
    } ]
   }
  }
 } ); 

});
```

```html
 <canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (admin.php?relatorios&acao=celulas:243)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3)

Como corrigir?

ADD:

Gerando o array `PHP` para enviar ao `$.ajax`:

```
$relatorioGr[$celulasReuniao->getIdCelula()][$i]["data"] = $celulasReuniao->getData();
$relatorioGr[$celulasReuniao->getIdCelula()][$i]["ofetas"] = $celulasReuniao->getOferta();
$relatorioGr[$celulasReuniao->getIdCelula()][$i]["decisoes"] = $celulasReuniao->getDecisoes();
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "_scripts/_php/_buscas/relatorioCelulas.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {dados},
    success: function (result) {
        window.dadosRel = result.data;              
    }
});
```

Comment: JavaScript não permite quebras de linha em strings como tens na pergunta. E esse JSON é uma Array, mas falta `[ ]` no inicio e fim da string. De onde vem essa string?

Comment: ah sm, coloquei quebra de linha só para ficar legivel mas no código não está assim, vê a adicional que coloquei na pergunta. Chegou a ver no https://repl.it/@CarlosRocha1/BewitchedBoilingBase?

Comment: Nesse link falta `[]` à volta do JSON. Não precisas da linha `JSON.parse(dados);` e falta valor para o primeiro `y`...

Comment: Alterei a pergunta

Comment: Podes colocar as linhas de código onde recebes o JSON do servidor?

Comment: recebo um array js. Adicionado no final da pergunta

Comment: Nesse caso `window.dadosRel` já é um objeto/array, não deves usar o `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro: suas chaves e valores(string) tem que estar entre aspas duplas. 
Segundo: Você esta usando dois elementos raiz.

Tenta ai:

```
{"data_1":{ 
  "label": "Gcéu 17", 
  "data": 
       [
         { 
            "x": "2019-03-01", 
            "y": 6
         },
         { 
            "x": "2019-03-03", 
            "y": 3
        }
       ]
},
"data_2":{ 
  "label": "Gcéu 18", 
  "data": 
       [
         {
             "x": "2019-03-02", 
             "y": 0
         },
         { 
             "x": "2019-03-05", 
             "y": 1
         }
       ]
}
}
```

Comment: tentei fazer consforme dito mas nao deu muito certo. eu coloquei na pergunta a minha tentativa, Vê onde errei fazendo favor? Precisa ser daquel jeito pois é para colcoar no Line Chart Gráfico

Comment: Alterei a pergunta